# ProgressDialog And Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I use `ProgressDialog` with Thread or `AsyncTask`.

Both of `AsyncTask` And Thread Work. But In finish the work `ProgressDialog` Dismiss And get force close .

In `onCreate()` i call this

```
new myAsyncTask().execute();
```

AsyncTask

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please Wait !",true,false);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        startProgram();
        return "";  
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Laurent he is doing it... Post your stacktrace

Comment: @Laurent its not necessary... but what is error.?

Comment: @Laurent onPost it is in UI thread

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: shows us this `startProgram()` part of the code. My guess updatingui from `doInbackground()`. Might be displaying a toast or something in statProgram.

Comment: what startProgram(); is doing becuse when you are running thread u cannot handle UI like settext or other thing check it

Comment: startProgram() work well (Copy file) I use this without Thread Very Well

Comment: @ArazJafaripur post startProgram and the logcat. someone deleted logcat details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `doInBackground` you call `startProgram`, which shows a `Toast` -- this is what causes the exception.
`Toasts` must be created from the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call  `onProgressUpdate(Integer...)` in `doInBackground()`

Refer this [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: codes inside in doInBackground() work . problem when occure the progressDialog dismiss .

Comment: @Same it not necessary to use this method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `Toast` in your `doInBackground()`. `Toast` needs to run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

try this
 `runOnUIThread` inside your `doInBackground()`.